# How to play a video Using Avplayer in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, avplayer

I am working with the `AVPlayer` in `UITableView` just like facebook is autoplaying videos in the timeline.

Playing videos is working fine.

The issue is when I scroll the indexPath, I need to change the video as well using URL.

I am using below code to play the video in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
  NSURL *videoURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.lifeLineAllPostArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"video_url"]];
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
           cell.videoItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:videoURL];
             dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                cell.videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:cell.videoItem];
                cell.avLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:cell.videoPlayer];
                cell.videoPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
 //                    cell.avLayer.frame = CGRectMake(5, 9, 310, 310);
//                    cell.avLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 250);
                cell.avLayer.frame=cell.picOrVideo.bounds;
                 cell.avLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
                [cell.picOrVideo.layer addSublayer:cell.avLayer];
                [cell.videoPlayer play];
                [cell.videoPlayer setVolume:1.0];
//            }

            });
        });
```

How can I play the different videos in each cell? At the top of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` i am using the below code for removing the player.

```
cell.picOrVideo.image=nil;
cell.playButtonOnVideo.image=nil;
cell.videoPlayer = nil;
cell.avLayer=nil;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: i think its not a good idea to play view in cellForRowAtIndexPath because its use more memory . and when your tableview reload at that time you face problem .

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya i am also facing same issue any solution.Tableview Reload I will handle that issue.Other wise any other solution

Comment: one tableviewcell didselectedindexpath deleagates method just open a new view and play video best solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39850431/6656894 refer this answer for your solution in this answer he want to change only play and stop button image and play audio file and now you can do same thing but forgot button icon and just play video in new controller if you want some example then i can help you .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42029030/4549304 Can you check this, if it helps?