# Display Image or AutoPlaying Video like Instagram feed

Tags: ios, swift, video, instagram

I want to create feed like Instagram where I can display Autoplaying video when I open the post or show Post(Image).

How can I achieve this using collectionView and only one cell for video and image?  [image]

Answer (score 1):

You could keep track of cells that are about to be displayed on the screen using `collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:` and the cells which are about to be removed using `collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:`.

Then use collectionView.convert to calculate which of those cells is currently most on screen, and then autoplay the video on that cell. Update the autoplaying when a user scroll is detected using `scrollViewDidScroll` and a new cell is more present on the screen.

We could have a post struct like this:

```
struct post {
  videoURL: String?
  imageURL: String?
}
```

In which a post with a video would have nil as imageURL value, and vice versa. When fetching posts you could put them inside an array.

Then you could look at your data, and use `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
      cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` to determine which kind of `UICollectionViewCell` to display at a certain index in your data array.

Comment: But how I display image and video on one view(collectionView cell) based on whatever the post is?

Comment: Make two different cells, one with UIImageView and one with perhaps an AVPlayer? Then depending on the indexPath and the data you have, decide which one to use.

Comment: My data would be dynamic, I can't set the cell depending on index path. I have to use one cell only and make it dynamic. But I'm not sure how?

Comment: Yes, dynamic data, but you have to store the data somehow, right? Probably in a list, which you increase the size of as the user scrolls and more data is fetched. You could have a data structure with an optional image and video url, if the image url is nil, display video cell, if the video url is nil, display an image cell.

Comment: sorry for bugging you but I'm still not sure how to use two cell, Can you please share some code anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this demo or code for autoplay video like instagram

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42029030/12729079

Comment: While this may solve the OP's issue, this is more suitable as either a comment or a vote to `Close -> Duplicate Of`. ... review [answer].